# Unable to click each li using For each loop

Tags: java, selenium

Can someone please help on below issues whichI am facing. In the below code its click on the first list then he came out without selecting the other `li`.

```
ActionBot.click(driver, RETAIL_APPLICATION_USER_MANAGEMENT_ADD_AUTHORITIES_CLICK_ON_SELECT_ROLE_DROPDOWN);
Retail_login.wait(4000);
WebElement ele=ActionBot.findElement(driver, RETAIL_APPLICATION_USER_MANAGEMENT_ADD_AUTHORITIES_GET_ALL_VALUE_FROM_SELECT_ROLE_DROPDOWN);

List<WebElement> columns = ele.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

System.out.println(columns.size() + "  values are there in role dropdown");

System.out.println("1");
if(val1.equals(Role))
{
    if(!ele2.isSelected())
    {
        ele2.click();
    }
    else{

    }       
}

System.out.println("2");

if(val1.equals(Role2))
{
    if(!ele2.isSelected())
    {
        ele2.click();
    }
}

System.out.println("3");

if(val1.equals(Role3))
{
    if(!ele2.isSelected())
    {
        ele2.click();
    }
}

System.out.println("4");
```

Can please someone help me on the above issues?

Comment: Where is the loop?

Comment: Where are you using for each loop?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use loop for List of elements:

```
//Get all li elements
List<WebElement> columns= ele.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
System.out.println(columns.size()+"  values are there in role dropdown");
//Click all the li element in the loop
for(WebElement val1:columns){
   val1.click();
}
```